# Video reading in opencv

Tags: opencv

I am new to opencv .I am trying to read video mp4 file but my code always says cannot open video device or file. I have placed video file in code folder .

```
VideoCapture capture;


capture.open("a.mp4");  // Open file


if (!capture.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Cannot open video device or file!" << endl;
    getch();
    return -1;
}

Mat frame;
namedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while(true)
{
    capture >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
        break;
    imshow("video", frame);
    if (waitKey(30) == 'q')
        break;
}
```

Comment: have you tried with any other videos or video formats?

Comment: yes i have tried avi format

Comment: is it in code folder or in build folder?

Comment: or make sure that the executable is in the same folder...

Comment: I have placed it in build folder but also tried to read by placing it it in code folder

Comment: I have placed it in same folder as that of executable but it won't works

Answer (score -3, accepted):

this is correct code for video and image reading. I don't know what was the exact error. But using different code  from orieally help me do my task in a different way.

```
// newproject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // Gaussian Blur
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>        // Basic OpenCV structures (cv::Mat, Scalar)
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //Image Reading
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "b.jpg" );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );

    //Video Reading

//  cvNamedWindow( "Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

//  CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "video.avi" );
//  IplImage* frame;

    /*  while(1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if( !frame ) break;
        cvShowImage( "Example2", frame );
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;//if user enter escape key then exit
    }*/

    //Summarize by sampling
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "video.avi" );
    if(!capture){
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage *bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);//Init the video read
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty (capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);

    CvSize size = cvSize((int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    //double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty (capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("Ayesha",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),fps,size);

    int x=0;
    while(1){
    x++;
        bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        if(!bgr_frame)
            break;

        if(x==19||x==21){
            cvShowImage("Example2",bgr_frame);
            cvWriteFrame( writer, bgr_frame );
        }

        if(x==20){
            cvShowImage("Example2",bgr_frame);
            cvWriteFrame( writer, bgr_frame );
            x=0;
        }
        char c=cvWaitKey(30);
        if (c==27) break;
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example2" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this answer in case someone came across this question as I did.

I was facing *almost* the same problem, trying to open a video file. My code worked with `.avi` but failed to open files with `.mp4` files.

Turns out openCV needs ffmpeg decoder to be installed on the system. In case of windows OS, you will need to copy `opencv_ffmpeg2411.dll` file into `C:\Windows\System32` directory. The DLL different systems can be found in OpenCV *extracted* directory.

Hope this helps someone.